# How to fix shaky frames that appear when rendering with motion blur?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, motion-blur

When I render my animation without motion blur it looks the following:
[image]

But when I render it with motion blur it comes with weird appearing frames:
[image]

I noticed that the frames that don't appear as they should have some kind of a circular pattern:
[image]
[image]

Here are my settings:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denoiser and motion blur don't mix. Turn it off.
Also, go to edit preferences > system, and turn on the GPU.
In the Cycles render option, select GPU (this will help your render speed with Motion blur). If your computer crashes, just leave it with CPU (I don't know the configuration of your machine).

Also, that black "blob" shadow smear you're getting it's because of sampling. By the looks of it, you have very few samples, if you're looking for a noisy look-film noir grain, ok. But if you're looking to get rid of the blob, turn them on past 120.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happens because *Motion Blur Position* is set to *Center on Frame* which centers the motion blur in every frame and if camera stops this happens. Change that to *Start on Frame*

[image]

Comment: Just a tip, you can take a screenshot of Blender's UI through *Window > Save Screenshot*.

Comment: I can't thank you more mate!!! It solved my rendering issue straight away!!!!! I've got some weird streaks popping out randomly on my characters, and they are all cleared after I set it to "Start on Frame"! Why do they set "Centre on Frame" as the default???